# Commons SCXML issues

Tags: java, apache-commons-scxml

I have been considering Commons SCXML implementation. It seems quite comprehensive but I have some unclear point.

In all the examples I have seen the states of the state machine are basically methods of a class that extends **AbstractStateMachine** class.

For small state charts this is okay but for machines with lots of states (IN BCSM like) this is an overkill.

Is there a possibility by default to have the states represented as classes (aka the StateMachine to be a composite of State)?

Comment: What would be the advantage of having each state represented as a class?

Comment: Can change the state implementation via a dependency inversion. Very useful while testing.
Closer to the **State** pattern design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:
**Control Isolator. A Control Flow Java library based on Apache Commons SCXML state machines.**

http://ramontalaverasuarez.blogspot.com.es/2012/10/ControlIsolator.html

It greatly simplifies working with SCXML.